# How can I resize an embedded video on GitHub flavoured markdown?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I recently added a video on a readme file on GitHub. Although I was able to drag and drop the video, it automatically fills the entire width of the readme. I was wondering if there was a way to adjust the height and width the video?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "I was able to drag and drop the video", but assuming that generates a `<video>` tag you should be able to add [a `height` or `width` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attributes) to it, e.g. as shown in the MDN documentation:

```html
<video controls width="250">
           <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
    <source src="/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/webm">

    <source src="/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

Comment: AFAICT MDN does not work on Github Flavored Markdown. I tested this and it does not work for me.

Comment: @achille, I'm not sure what you mean by that. MDN isn't a library or custom tool of some kind, it's just really high quality documentation for web developers. GitHub does strip some tags and attributes out, but whatever tags it generates for videos should work. Can you provide clarity on the rendered HTML that gets generated? OP didn't give much detail.

Comment: When OP says 'drag and drop the video', they are referring to [this recent GitHub feature for videos](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/attaching-files). Which just generates a link, so no html tags. Embedding said link in the HTML tags you posted does not render as expected.

Comment: "Which just generates a link, so no html tags"—surely there are HTML tags in the rendered output?

Comment: Github flavored markdown only supports a limited set of HTML tags (complete list [in the code](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-pipeline/blob/main/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L44-L48)). `<video>` isn't one of them.